# WM_PAINT Hook using SetWindowsHookEx

Tags: visual-c++, setwindowshookex

Here Goes My Code

```
// hook.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

LRESULT CALLBACK GetMsgProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){
int __;
cout << "Hallo World" << endl;
SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, GetMsgProc, 0, 0);
cin >> __;
return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK GetMsgProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
cout << code << endl;
return 0;
}
```

I am trying to get WM_PAINT event... at the moment I am trying to trap all the events. Where I am Missing ?

Answer (score -2):

Read the documentation please. It clearly states why your usage is incorrect especially with regard to the last two parameters. If you want to hook every thread you need to provide a module 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Sorry can you be a bit more elaborate ? I've read the link it says `If this parameter is zero, the hook procedure is associated with all existing threads running in the same desktop as the calling thread.` regarding the last parameter.

Comment: Read the documentation for the other parameters too. "A pointer to the hook procedure. If the dwThreadId parameter is zero or specifies the identifier of a thread created by a different process, the lpfn parameter must point to a hook procedure in a DLL. Otherwise, lpfn can point to a hook procedure in the code associated with the current process. " "An error may occur if the hMod parameter is NULL and the dwThreadId parameter is zero or specifies the identifier of a thread created by another process. "

Comment: My lpfn is in the current process. But my dwThreadId is supposed to be 0 I hope ?? is this the scenario ?? I am pretty messed up here. on this simple(probably) thing. and I am very n00b to VC++. Please I cannot understand what I should do.