# How to color a specific pixel in windows console

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ programming and I find it interesting and fun to learn.
Can anybody give me an idea in setting color for a specific pixel in a windows console while the color will stay permanent even the windows console is refreshed or moved.

I used  Setpixel() for my recent code.Here are some code snippets assuming it inside the body of a function:

```
    HWND myconsole = GetConsoleWindow();
    HDC dc = GetDC(myconsole);
    COLORREF color = RGB(255,120,120);
    for(int count =0;count<100;count++)
    {
    SetPixel(dc,0,count,color);
    }
```

Any idea and opinion would be a great help.Thanks!

Comment: Your current code is changing the pixel on the *screen*, which just happens to be over the console window. This is obviously not what you want. Problem is, the console doesn't work in pixels, it works in character blocks. It is, after all, text-only. Look into using the `WriteConsoleOutput` function to output colored text (among other things).

Comment: The console can only be accessed per character and whatever modifications you might do on one of the characters, it won't survive clearing the console.

Comment: If you really need this, try a hook: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432551/wm-paint-hook-using-setwindowshookex

Comment: I  understand your comment... I will try this!!.thanks.. maybe i have some further follow up questions so just stand by..

Comment: @user Are you sure that will even work? I don't think the console window receives WM_PAINT messages. It is not like a normal window. Peter, if you want a normal window that you can draw into, then just create one and process the WM_PAINT message yourself.

Comment: @user  I have try WriteConsoleOutput and it is the one I am actually looking. the color will stay permanenty even if i moved and refresh the console... Thanks for sharing...

Comment: aw sorry @ Cody Gray not user.wahaha..Thanks pal

Comment: @PeterG if you're looking for what WriteConsoleOutput describes, you might change the questions' title from 'pixel' to 'character cell'.

Answer (score 2):

Either you're question was unclear or you changed you're mind subsequently and decided you wanted to draw on a Win32 window, not a Win32 console window. In any case here are answers for both questions.

1. Drawing to a Win32 window (not a console)

You can draw to a Win32 project a number of ways (including graphics APIs like OpenGL and DirectX). The simplest way is to use Windows GDI (Graphics Device Interface) which is simply a number of functions which are part of Windows.h.

SetPixel() will draw to whichever Device Context you give it a handle to (the first argument). This handle must be to the Device Context of your main window if you wish to draw on the window (you could also give it a handle to an off-screen surface like a backbuffer).

So to get the handle to the Device Context of your main window use: GetDC(hWnd) where hWnd is a handle to your main window. The returned Device Context handle can be used in SetPixel() to draw to the window.

```
HDC _hWindowDC = GetDC(_hWnd);
SetPixel(_hWindowDC, _iXpos, _iYpos, _myColorRef);
```

If you want to draw to Device Context like you are trying to do, you need to make a Win32 Project, not a Win32 Console project.

2. Drawing to a Win32 console project

As mentioned in the comments, for a console project, you can only "draw" characters, not pixels. For example you could pick a screen coordinate and cout some characters like so:

```
COORD point; 

point.X = _iX; 
point.Y = _iY; 

SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), point); 
cout << "Whatever";
```

Comment: @ Serge, your answer is likey  displaying  "Whatever "string  in the specified coordinates in the console screen by the function SetConsoleCursorPosition. Yes i can draw with the SetConsoleCursorPosition function using a console project.. Using Win32 project how can i  set colors to a specified pixel.?

Comment: @Peter G,  You can draw to a Win32 project a number of ways (including graphics APIs like OpenGL and DirectX). The simplest way is to use Windows GDI (Graphics Device Interface) which is part of <windows.h>.

SetPixel() will draw to whichever Device Context you give it a handle to (the first argument). This handle must be to the Device Context of your main window. So to get the handle use: GetDC(hWnd) where hWnd is a handle to your main window. The returned Device Context handle can be used in SetPixel() to draw to the window. 

Let me know if you want this up as answer. Can add code / library

Answer (score 0):

@Cody Gray this is  the snippets when i tried WriteConsoleOutput.This is  not so great but maybe it can help other.. if someone can give idea and correct some logics and misconception here then it is better.. thanks

```
    const CHAR_INFO *buffer;
    CHAR_INFO buffer1;
    buffer = &buffer1;
    buffer1. Char. AsciiChar= '-';
    buffer1.Attributes = 0x0001;
    const SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES *securityAttribute;
    HANDLE writeConsole= GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    HANDLE readConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD buffer1Size={10,10};
    COORD position = { 4,4};
    SMALL_RECT  display ={4,4,50,50};
   WriteConsoleOutput(writeConsole,buffer,buffer1Size,position,&display);
```